# Creating Timeline Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got problem with creating timeline in laravel

I have data that lists an activity for a time:

```
id profile activity        created_at            updated_at
1    1      eat        2018-11-25 14:54:46 2018-12-25 14:54:46
2    1      playing    2018-11-25 14:54:46 2018-12-25 14:54:46
```

this is how code work now

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <div class="timeline">
      <div class="timeline__wrap">
          <div class="timeline__items">
               @foreach ($results as $result)
                 @if ($result->activity === 'eat') 
                 <div class="timeline__item">
                     <div class="timeline__content">
                     //script ....content</div>
                     </div> 
                 </div>
                 @elseif ($result->activity === 'playing')

                 @elseif ($result->activity === 'sleep')

                 @endif
               @endforeach
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the result like this 
[image: result]
but the problem, i want the result show all activity, activity only consists of eat, playing, and sleep, but in the database only has 2 activities namely eating and playing. How to show all activity in looping area to know finish or not

```
<div class="panel-body">
       <div class="timeline">
          <div class="timeline__wrap">
              <div class="timeline__items">
                     <div class="timeline__item">
                         <div class="timeline__content">
                              <p class="activity-finish"> Eat </>
                         </div> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="timeline__item">
                         <div class="timeline__content">
                              <p class="activity-finish"> Playing </>
                         </div> 
                     </div>
                     <div class="timeline__item">
                         <div class="timeline__content">
                              <p class="activity-not-done"> Sleep</>
                         </div> 
                     </div>
               </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

the result should be like this

[image: result i hope]

Thank you

Comment: Hi there and thank you for all the information! I am a little unclear on what you are trying to accomplish -- are you asking how to structure your database so that it includes "sleeping", or are you asking how to attach a **start** and **stop** to each activity with the assumption that a user is "sleeping" in between unaccounted for time slots?

Comment: Or is there a fixed sequence of activities, like `start -> eat -> play -> sleep -> finish`?

Comment: thank for your comment @JeremyHarris , i want to show user is "sleeping" but in database i dont have activity name is "sleeping"

Comment: all activities are displayed before the results come, all activities are the same namely eat, playing, and sleep

Comment: You can add to $results hardcoded way. `$results[] = ["activity" => "sleep"]`. So before returning `$results` iterate through it and add `sleep` if not found.

Comment: @BonnyAUlia Can you review the comments here and help point us in the right direction? For me at least, the problem is still unclear.

Comment: Hai@JeremyHarris, if i use foreach for the result, the timeline show two activity of three, how to show all activity with hardcoded and compare the result from the database. for example `if $result->activity === 'sleep'`, the class change with "activity-finish". if i just get all from the database, the activity just show two activity and sleeping not show

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding you correctly but

```
@elseif ($result->activity === 'sleep')

@endif
```

here will never run if "sleep" isn't a valid activity. Do you want to change this to an else statement? If there are only 3 options and sleep is the fall through.

Comment: As pointed out, "sleep" isn't an activity in the database, so I do not believe this solution will work.

Comment: Can't comment on the original post unfortunately. But right you are, kinda need to see what is coming from the controller. Was assuming there'd be some token designating no activity.

Comment: Thank for your comment and help,
if the sleep activity was created, the timeline show all activity, but now just show two of three activity, i want to show all activity, no problem if hard coded or not, the result must compare with the hard code

Comment: So you don't want to create the sleep activity at the moment? But still want it to appear?
If this is the case, just add `$results[] = ["activity" => "sleep"]` to the array in your controller before passing it to the view as @Oen44 suggested. (or just do it in the view sure)

Comment: hai @DylanHobbs, what can i do if just add in view? Thank

Comment: You'll need to add "sleep" to the array of results.
You can do this in the controller or the view with the same line of code.
`$results[] = ["activity" => "sleep"]`
You'll need to wrap it in `<?php ... ?>` tags in the view of course and add it before you iterate over the array,